# WebView is Not Reacting to my tapGesture How It's Possible?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, uiwebviewdelegate

> "i Have An Application On which i got six Web View to display the content
>    i have put the touch event action on all of them  through GestureRecognizer  But It Can't Get The Action What Can Be The Problem
>     is It So that Web View Don't Capture  the Gesture Event  ?"

Thanks a lot  in  Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enable "User interaction enabled" from IB.